# Unable to find timezonedb.so

Tags: php, apache

I was attempting to use a new library today that I found on the internet to convert HTML to PDF since it has recently become apparent that wkhtmltopdf is not an option since I do not seem to have proper permissions on the webserver I am using. I am using the library Htmltofpdf.

when I run the file that calls the library I get this error every time (if I remove the require statement I no longer get the error)

the error I am getting is

> [26-Aug-2012 13:11:05] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/timezonedb.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/timezonedb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

does anyone know how I can go about fixing this - my tech support for my site "luckily" is in india and they dont understand what I need unless I spell it out for them.

Comment: The error explains itself...have you tried installing the library?

Comment: do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Go to your PHP folder installation, mine is `/etc/php5` and go to the `apache2` folder, there you'll find a `php.ini`file, open and search for `.so` and you'll get to the lines where you need to define the libraries you want it to load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your library is included in the php.ini settings:
e.g :

```
extension=/path/to/extension/timezonedb.so
```

You can just drop the library in `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/` and then in your php.ini add the following line:

```
extension=timezonedb.so
```

Comment: appears 

    pecl install timezonedb

should do it however I dont have permission on my webserver-  I am seeing if they will do it for me

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar warning in my error log.

My `php.ini` already had the `timezonedb.os` entry, but the library was missing at the extension folder.

I asked my provider to fix the issue and they did, but instead of include the library they **commented out** the `timezonedb.so` in `php.ini`.

The warning disappeared from the error.log.  I guess the library is not needed in my PHP version 5.2.17

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar warning in my error log - on SLES11-SP2. 
I commented out the line:

```
extension = timezonedb.so
```

in  `/etc/php5/conf.d/timezonedb.ini` 
and the warning disappeared (after restart of apache2).